# How to open new tab of browser when click the link of "more"

Tags: python, openerp-7

How could I open new tab of browser when user click the link "Open New Tap" from "More" of tree view?
[image]

Comment: use <a href="your url" target="_blank">open new tab</a>

Comment: Thank Dheerendra, but OpenERP is using xml format for view.

Answer (score 0):

Add target Attribute to your action

```
<act_window
            id="action_unhold_status_update"
            name="UnHold"
            context="{'status_action': 'hold'}"
            res_model="wizard.set.status"
            src_model="sale.order"
            target="new"
            view_mode="form"
            view_type="form"
            key2="client_action_multi"
            />
```